# Install Mpdf 8.0.11 library without COMPOSER

Tags: composer-php, mpdf, php-8

I updated PHP to version 8.0 in windows server 2019 with web platform.
But:

1. I can't install COMPOSER because it gives me several missing library problems ...
2. I can't update the mpdf library if I don't have COMPOSER.

How can I install mpdf without using composer?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I install Composer PHP packages without Composer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40545795/how-do-i-install-composer-php-packages-without-composer)

Comment: Also, why not fix those problems from point 1? Installing packages using Composer is way easier than doing it without Composer

Comment: There is a whole documentation page dedicated to this topic https://mpdf.github.io/installation-setup/using-without-composer.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I install mpdf 7 without composer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50280869/how-do-i-install-mpdf-7-without-composer)

Comment: Hi everyone, I solved!
I installed mpdf with Composer on my local pc and then I copied ALL the folders that composer had created on the server where I have my applications and the library works. Thank you all very much1